# Assigning too many parameters for procedure when having just only one table value parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using asp.net(C#), .NET 4, SQL Server 2012, IIS7.

I want to import the excel data to sql server by using table valued parameters. but I'm experiencing a problem. 
Here is the partial code:

**C#**

```
//extract excel data, only 10 fixed rows.
myEXcnnstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Exfullname + ";    Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
myEXcnn = new OleDbConnection(myEXcnnstring);
myEXcnn.Open();
myEXsql = "select '" + ExCompany + "' as mycompany,'" + ExProject + "' as myproject,'" + Exdate.ToShortDateString() + "' as mydate,* from [sheet1$A1:N10]";
myEXcmd = new OleDbCommand(myEXsql, myEXcnn);
myEXda = new OleDbDataAdapter(myEXcmd);
myEXdt = new DataTable();
myEXds = new DataSet();
myEXda.Fill(myEXds);
myEXdt = myEXds.Tables[0];
myEXcnn.Close();

// load to SQL SERVER
mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
mycmd.CommandText = "dbo.loadCost";
SqlParameter tvpParam = mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TVPCost", myEXdt);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.TVP_Cost";
mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
myCnn.Close();
```

**SQL server define TVP**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TVP_Cost] AS TABLE(
[mycompany] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[myproject] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[mydate] [date] NOT NULL,
[mytype] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Area1] [numeric](18, 8) NOT NULL,
[Area2] [numeric](18, 8) NOT NULL,
--etc 
)
GO
```

**SQL Server Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[loadCost]
    @TVPCost dbo.TVP_Cost readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Costtest (co1, co2,co3,co4,co5) 
    SELECT co1, co2, co3, co4, co5 from @TVPcost
END
```

The error message is that I'm given too many parameters to procedure. But I only have one parameters, a table-valued parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you're not declaring `mycmd`.  Is it possible that you used that Command object earlier, and that it has already some parameters in it?

Command objects are cheap, I always grab a new one:

```
var cmd = MyConnection.CreateCommand();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made a stupid mistake. forgot to initial a new one.